# Why can ArrayList elements not be converted to ints?

Tags: java, arraylist

I know I have done this in the past. I have an ArrayList that has been populated with integers. I need to iterate over it and find the maximum value. However, when I iterate over an array with something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    if (list.get(i) > max)
    { 
        max = list.get(i);
    }
}
```

I get an error that says java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int or that > is a bad operand type. I have never encountered this before, and I have used arraylists multiple times for this same purpose. What am I doing wrong here?

max is declared as an int but is not initialized.

Comment: A guess: `list` is `List<Object>` or `List`.

Comment: try to post more code

Comment: You must be declaring your list like this: `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: This code doesn't say much about the cause of the problem, but I'd guess you declared the list without generic parameter.

Comment: [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-). No need for reinvention of circular components intended to rotate on an axle bearings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you declared the ArrayList just like this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of :

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I did. I'm such a dope. Thanks. I just hopped back into learning after taking a month off, and I forgot the syntax.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)
Good luck with the learning.

Comment: @JoeSchmuck more importantly, just use `Collections.max`.